# Dynamic input is not recognized in struts2-jquery tags

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

In my application i need to change the content of the `<s:textfield>` dynamically
my code is given below:

```jsp
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.subscribe('before', function(event, data) {                
        $('#text').val('Text Changed by jQuery');
    });               
</script>       

<s:form id="form2" action="textchange" >        
    <s:textfield id="text" name="text" value="Hello World!!!"/>                                                        
    <sj:submit  targets="result" onBeforeTopics="before" />
</s:form>
```

my expecting output is

```
Text Changed by jQuery
```

but I'm getting

```
Hello World!!!
```

I'm using Struts2-jQuery-plugin 3.5.1.
How to get the dynamic output?

Comment: where you are getting old value? in your action class or in jsp itself?

Comment: Put `subscribe` in document ready block.

Comment: im getting my old value in my actionclass

Comment: Do you need ajax call or plain submit is enough?

Comment: i need ajax call by using sj:submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: This is not the best way to do that.

But remove subscribe and `onBeforeTopics` attribute. Add id to submit button and bind click event to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#form2Submit").click(function() {   
      $('#text').val('Text Changed by jQuery');
    });
  });
</script>

<s:form id="form2" action="textchange">        
  <s:textfield id="text" name="text" value="Hello World!!!" />                                                        
  <sj:submit id="form2Submit" targets="result" />
</s:form>
```

*Any other way.* Using `<sj:a>` tag with subscribe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $.subscribe('before', function(event, data) {        
      $('#text').val('Text Changed by jQuery');
    }); 
  });
</script>

<s:form id="form2" action="textchange">        
  <s:textfield id="text" name="text" value="Hello World!!!" />                                                        
  <sj:a targets="result" onClickTopics="before" formIds="form2" button="true">
    Submit
  </sj:a>
</s:form>
```

Comment: @Hariprasath: If it works that what is the problem? Accept/upvote this answer.

Comment: @AleksandrM:I strongly believe that SO should put it mandatory to comment if someone is down voting

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: That and some people shouldn't able downvote at all. :(

Answer (score 1):

The `before` is running after the form is serialized, so the old value is used. You need to modify code like this

```jsp
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#before').click(function() {
       $('#text').val('Text Changed by jQuery');
   });
  });
</script>
<s:div id="result"/>
<s:form id="form2" action="textchange" method="POST">
<s:textfield id="text" name="text" value="Hello World!!!"/>
<sj:submit  id="before" targets="result" />
</s:form>
```

Comment: i've tried so many ways, i dont know what's the right way to do it. please help me to get the dynamic value in my ActionClass.

Comment: @RomanC: I strongly believe that SO should put it mandatory to comment if someone is down voting